# I want to store the predictions on mongodb and it auto increment the value against it

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

J= hammer, firearm, scissors
Pred_classes[j]

Now i want to create a mongo db database like

Scissor : 0
Firearm : 2
Hammer : 1

And after each prediction on the frame the value of above mentioned items get incremented ...like if my model predicts hammer in one frame then the value in front of it get +1.

Kindly help me to make a mongodb query for the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collection.update_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update%20one#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method with [$inc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to increment values

Depending on yours collection structure, you will have something like that:

```
mongo.db.coll.update_one({"_id": "scissor"}, {"$inc": 1})
```